# Django 3 TemplateDoes not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

Even though I am providing correct path  it still giving me an error. in this project have made custom user model so I am not able to understand where i am going wrong.

[image: project tree]

And also added the required paths in settings. I tried the same code even by using include method in urls,py but still failed. where exactly i am making mistake?

setting.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'fw4g6x*9vn6sz)&v*$q-gppcwgd-%0&oo6_ydt(3t!#&uyz=xt'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'account',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

register.html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="register1" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in registeration_form %}
    <p>
        {{field.label_tag}}
        {{field}}

        {if field.help_text %}
            <small style="color:grey;">{{field.help_text}}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% fr error in field.errors %}
    <p style="color:red;">{{error}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from account.views import (
register,
)
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from account.forms import RegistrationForm

def register(request):
    context ={}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            aadhar = form.cleaned_data('aadhar')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data('password1')
            account = authenticate(aadhar=aadhar,password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/register.html',  context)
```

Error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /register/

account/register.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version:     3.0.4
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

account/register.html

Exception Location:     E:\phptodj\test1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  E:\phptodj\test1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.4
Python Path:    

['E:\\phptodj\\test1',
 'E:\\phptodj\\test1',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3',
 'E:\\phptodj\\test1\\venv',
 'E:\\phptodj\\test1\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 17 Mar 2020 12:32:53 +0000
```

Comment: Please edit your question with your templates settings and directories layout - and you can remove the models and urls code, they are irrelevant for this issue ;-)

Comment: made changes as you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings of the template in `settings.py` should be...

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And your folder structure should be...

```
project_name
     |
   app_1
     |
   app_2
     |
  account
     |
  templates
     |
     |__account
           |
           |__register.html
```

Comment: While using named urls is BestPractice, `redirect()` also accepts a path or a full url. And this has nothing to do with the OP's problem anyway.

Comment: their i would be inserting success page

Comment: Where is your success page mean what is the path of success page template?

Comment: even before getting this page i would like to see register page , I tried your way still no change

Comment: Mean you are not able to load the register page cz while loading the register page you will get above error, right?

Comment: Ok np, feel relax, can you please add your folder structure and the variable `TEMPLATES` of settings.py .

Comment: please move your `register.html` from `account` to `templates -> account -> register.html` and your problem will be solved.